# Toggle button images are of small size but toggle button takes more space

Tags: android, layout, togglebutton

I want to add two images at the different states of toggle button. 
The Images are changing as i have used the selector but the size of toggle button is very big as compared to image.

Actually ,my images are of smaller size and the toggle button is taking much space and it disturbs my layout.

Please  give solution.

Comment: post your layout code.otherwise no one help you!!!

Comment: You should add your layout code in order to help other users to understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a file like this in your drawable folder and use it as background of that
view in android view

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal" android:state_activated="false" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_activated="true" />

</selector>
```